# wpdb prepare placeholders for MySQL keywords

Tags: wpdb

I have a function that takes inputs that will be used for keywords in the query. I want to use placeholders for these things in the query string, as otherwise there will be a sqli vulnerability.

Here's my function:

```
 function get_things ($args = array()) {
  global $wpdb;

  $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "my_table ORDER BY %s %s",
     $args['order_by'],
     $args['order']
  );

  $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
}
```

The second placeholder will be a MySQL keyword (either `ACS` or `DESC`). The problem with the above function is that the keyword will be wrapped in quotes. How can I fix this, whilst not creating a sqli vulnerability?

Also, the first placeholder (which will be a column name) is also being wrapped in quotes, which I don't want and is causing issues.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939418/how-to-use-prepare-with-dynamic-column-names/30939945

Comment: `$wpdb->prepare()` doesn't handle column names well, so you have to find another way around it. Using pre-approved values allows you to add these dynamically without making your query vulnerable.